# display database datatable info as label array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable

It was hard to find the correct question topic. Well, let me elaborate more. I'm making a barcode generator simple webapp. It is for our warehouse team.

I made a class named `SqlComm` where I handle all `SQL` connection related thing. Then, I have a query (the query is just about counting a column where some Date in between). I use the query for setting the `array` size. Later, it loops through a `for` cycle and adds each new label to a placeholder. Sadly, the placeholder is not showing my new labels just created.

c# (codebehing)

```
  int index = 0;
  int iLength = 0;

  dt = SqlComm.SqlDataTable("SELECT [Lenum] FROM [SUIDonMachineTable] WHERE MachineTimestamp  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'"+strDayFrom+"', 121) AND CONVERT(datetime,'"+strDayTo+"', 121) AND Station ='NG08NX1BT'");

  object obj = new object();
  obj = SqlComm.SqlReturn("SELECT COUNT (Lenum) FROM [SUIDonMachineTable] WHERE MachineTimestamp  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'"+strDayFrom+"', 121) AND CONVERT(datetime,'"+strDayTo+"', 121) AND Station ='NG08NX1BT'");
  iLength = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
  Label[] labels = new Label[iLength];

  for (index = 0; index == iLength; index++)
     {                        
         labels[index] = new Label();
         labels[index].Text = (string)dt.Rows[index]["Lenum"];
         PH.Controls.Add(labels[index]);                                
     }
```

asp.net (placeholder part)

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PH" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: all my `labels[]` array is getting data. It is just not displayed. May be another approach to doing this would be enough (instead of using placeholders).

Comment: Where you have written this code? On some button click? Have you checked the html renedered on browser?

Comment: @krshekhar No, I haven't. Yes, it is from a submit button.

Comment: You're potentially open to SQL Injection, given the way you concatenate strings; you should be using parameterized queries in this type of situation.  Also, C# has a `DateTime` type, which should remove the need for converting.  One more thing - never use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types _especially_ in SQL Server;  [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) should explain handily.  It's also the wrong way to think about date/time, anyways.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: the dynamically created controls lost after the post back. so you can follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102483/asp-net-user-controls-added-to-placeholder-dynamically-cannot-retrieve-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (index = 0; index < iLength; index++)
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the post-back. As the dynamically created control value lost after post back.
[Accessing controls added programmatically on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763050/accessing-controls-added-programmatically-on-postback)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18080/Solve-Dynamic-Control-Problem-With-PostBack

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nothing because the loop is not reached because of `index == iLength` try with `index < iLength`